# Getting 'invalid_grant' error with google oauth from second time

Tags: python-2.7, google-oauth

I am using google oAuth for my python application in which I have feature to automatically logging in by google into my app. When I try to login first time, it will be successfull, but from next time if I will login it doesn't success and each time I gets 500 internal server error.

When I checked error logs, I got following error message on 'credentials = oAuthFlow.step2_exchange(code)' line

```
Failed to retrieve access token: {
    "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

I have valid clientId registered on google.
Can anybody tell me why is it happening. I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 6):

It could be caused by any number of things, including ...

1. User has withdrawn permission
2. The scopes have changed
3. Google has retired your refresh token
4. Bugs in your code which are presenting the wrong refresh token. Remember you will ONLY get a refresh token the first time through. On subsequent calls the refresh token will be null because you should have saved it in your database.

I get it a lot when I use the same user for both testing and live use since the two refresh tokens tend to overwrite each other.

The good news is that whatever the cause, the solution is always the same. You need to force a re-authorization from your user.